# Bootstrap / JQuery issue when running project

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, datepicker

Morning folks,

I am using Visual studio 2013 and have an MVC project that I am working that uses the Bootstrap Twitter datepicker.   I have no issue with the datepicker on my form as such, this does work.

I have added to my site via nuget package manager the following:

- bootstrap V3.3.5.
- jquery 3.1.1
- jquery-ui-1.12.1.

When I run the project the I get the following pop up message:
[image]

If I press the continue button the message box goes away and the page is then loaded.  When I test the bootstrap datepicker on my text box this renders fine.

On my Create.chstml I have referenced the following links and scripts at the top of my page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can see that the version of jquery and bootstrap are compatible and that jquery is referenced above bootstrap so I am not to sure why I am getting this error?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is not compatible with jQuery 3.0 and above at the moment. So latest version of jQuery that can be used with Bootstrap 3 is 2.2.4.

Although, [some reported](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834#issuecomment-228271973) that it works with jQuery Migrate.

You can check this [discussion](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834) for more info

-Help :)

Comment: thanks for the discussion thread above, that's great help and an interesting read.  I completed many of the suggestions on this page but this has not solved my issue.   I have added the jQuery migrate package to run alongside JQuery 3 > but this has not worked.  I have also stripped down my nugel packages and reinstalled via package manager jQuery 2.2.4 with the ui version of 1.12.1 and bootstrap 3 but this is still producing an error.   Many thanks for your help, at least I know why its not working and will look for another datepicker solution.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

provides this link at top of all the css & js link